# Date period with breaks: make 3 rows out of 2

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Edit: added an id, to make it more graspable

I stumbled over this problem a couple of times and always solved it per `PL/SQL`, but I am wondering, if there is a SQL-solution.

There is a table with a `from_date` and a `to_date`. The data in there is seamless for every `to_date`, there is a new row with a `from_date` on the next day.

```
create table test_date
(
  id number,
  from_date date,
  to_date date
)
/

insert into test_date values(1, to_date('01022003', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('28022003', 'ddmmyyyy'))
/

insert into test_date values(2, to_date('01032003', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('31032003', 'ddmmyyyy'))
/
```

There is another table, which breaks this time periods.

```
create table test_date2
(
  id number,
  from_date date,
  to_date date
)
/

insert into test_date2 values(3, to_date('05022003', 'ddmmyyyy'), to_date('10022003', 'ddmmyyyy'))
/
```

So, I want a view, that shows this time periods and the "breaks" in different columns, but this should also be seamless after the "break" with `test_date2` it should go right on with the data in `test_date` and I can't get that going:

```
select typ, id, from_date, decode(typ, 1, decode(to_date+1, lead_from_date, to_date, lead_from_date-1), to_date) to_date
from(
select typ, id, from_date, to_date, lead(from_date) over (order by from_date, typ) lead_from_date
from 
(select 1 typ, id, from_date, to_date
   from test_date t
union all 
select 2 typ, id, from_date, to_date
   from test_date2 t2
   ) a
   )
```

What I get here is

```
1   1   01/02/2003  04/02/2003
2   3   05/02/2003  10/02/2003
1   2   01/03/2003
```

the period between `11/02/2003` and `28/02/2003` (for the row in `test_data` with `id=1`) is missing.

So, what I want, is this:

```
1   1   01/02/2003  04/02/2003
2   3   05/02/2003  10/02/2003
1   1   11/02/2003  28/02/2003
1   2   01/03/2003
```

Comment: what pattern do you follow to know the typ and id of the new row?

Comment: The new row just starts(from_date) where the to_date of test_date2 ends and the row in test_data(with the specific id) should still be active

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after; your're not getting the same answer because you're not generating the full list of dates. If you normalise your data in order to get a unique list of dates you can then use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to find the next/previous date, and re-generate your list.

I use `UNPIVOT` here to transform the `from_date` and `to_date` into a single column but 4 unions will provide the same result:

```
with all_tables as (
 select *
   from test_date
  union all
 select *
   from test_date2
        )
 , all_dates as (
 select dt
   from all_tables
unpivot ( dt for dates in ( from_date, to_date ))
        )
select dt
     , lead(dt) over (order by dt) as to_date
  from all_dates;

DT         TO_DATE
---------- ----------
01/02/2003 05/02/2003
05/02/2003 10/02/2003
10/02/2003 28/02/2003
28/02/2003 01/03/2003
01/03/2003 31/03/2003
31/03/2003

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: I am not sure, if I oversimplified the problem, so I edited the question. Your solution might still give me enough hints to solve it.

Comment: You haven't oversimplified but you're edit makes this even more confusing... you've misnamed the tables in your description and you're asking for something that's in the final output. Could you just post the _exact_ answer that you want so there's something sensible to work towards?